# fb frame height stuck at 800px

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

My facebook app iframe height is stuck at 800px. I have it set at a fixed height of 2800 in the app admin panel on facebook developers. some style cladd called .canvas_iframe_util is setting it to 800px and I cant change it or edit it. I assume its coming in from facebook. Anybody any thoughts?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue, after doing lots of R&D I came up with the following solution for different browsers. So I implemented different styles for html and body for all browsers. Its working on every browser now :)

```
<?php
$u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
{
 $style_overflow = "overflow:hidden;";
}
else
{
    $style_scroll = "scroll='no'";
}
?>

<html style="<?php echo $style_overflow; ?>" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<!---other html code -->
<body style="<?php echo $style_overflow; ?>" <?php echo $style_scroll;?>>       

<script>
var fbAppId = '<?php echo FB_APP_ID?>';

window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init(
        {
            appId: '<?php echo FB_APP_ID ?>',
            status:true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true, 
            oauth: true
        }
    );


     function sizeChangeCallback() {

        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    }
     FB.XFBML.parse();

     FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(); 


};
(function()
{
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'; //hi_IN for language plugins
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this function and set body overflow as hidden

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: xx, height: XX });
}
```

AND

```
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

AND do remember to change the height to fluid in admin panel